# Why is this error about Grunt when starting sails

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I am using node 0.12.2 and sails 0.10.5

After doing

```
sudo npm install
```

sails fails to lift. I have to

```
sudo npm install cookie
```

and then

```
sudo npm install connect
```

to make sails lift. Then it shows some error like this:

```
error: Grunt :: module.js:338
   throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ec2-user/someuser/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

and

```
sudo npm install grunt-cli
```

does not do anything. nor does installing it globally.

```
sudo npm -g install grunt-cli
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
/usr/local/lib
└── grunt-cli@0.1.13 

[ec2-user@ip-172-*****]$ sails lift

info: Starting app...

error: Grunt :: module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ec2-user/someuser/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Sails still can lift but where does this error come from and how to get rid of it?

Comment: not helping. Please see the edited version above

Comment: I have updated my answer below to include running `sails lift` from project folder

Answer (score 3):

The error message pretty describe what's wrong

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ec2-user/someuser/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt'
```

`grunt-cli` is missing. You need to install it using (might need sudo)

```
npm install grunt-cli -g
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Make sure you are running `sails lift` from your sails project folder. (to me it looks like you are running it from root which is probably the cause of the issue)

Otherwise, I leave my other suggestions here:

Install sails globally: `npm -g install sails`
Install grunt globally: `npm -g install grunt-cli`

If the problem still exists after running `npm install` it is very likely to be related to permission issues. You can fix this permission problems using one of two options:

- Change the permission to npm's default directory.
- Change npm's default directory to another directory.

I recommend the latter.
Here is an official guide from NPM people on how to do both: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: not working after changing permission or installing globally